# Getting access to :not_found, :internal_server_error etc. in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actioncontroller

It looks like `ActionController::StatusCodes` has been removed from Rails 3.

I used synonyms for HTTP status codes such as

```
200 => :ok
404 => :not_found
500 => :internal_server_error
```

For more codes, see here:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render#254-List-of-status-codes-and-their-symbols

Where can I find these in Rails 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the error codes reside in `action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb` where the symbols are mapped to actual exceptions:

```
  'ActionController::RoutingError'             => :not_found,
  'AbstractController::ActionNotFound'         => :not_found,
  'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound'               => :not_found,
  'ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError'             => :conflict,
  'ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid'                => :unprocessable_entity,
  'ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved'               => :unprocessable_entity,
  'ActionController::MethodNotAllowed'         => :method_not_allowed,
  'ActionController::NotImplemented'           => :not_implemented,
  'ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken' => :unprocessable_entity
```

However the mappings of the 100 - 400 range are gone from Rails, probably because they are [already present in Rack](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L397).

Comment: Hi @jakub. Does this look like a possible source?https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb

Comment: Yep that's most likely it. I was thinking that it might be somewhere in Rack (thus outside my Rails copy).

Answer (score 3):

Ruby on Rails uses [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/). The status codes are defined in Rack::Utils:

```
HTTP_STATUS_CODES = {
  100  => 'Continue',
  101  => 'Switching Protocols',
  102  => 'Processing',
  200  => 'OK',
  201  => 'Created',
  ...
}
```

Then those are used to create symbols (i.e. `:switching_protocols`):

```
SYMBOL_TO_STATUS_CODE = Hash[*HTTP_STATUS_CODES.map { |code, message|
  [message.downcase.gsub(/\s|-/, '_').to_sym, code]
}.flatten]
```

The whole code is [browsable here](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L397).