# How does Rails calculate the response code for actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How does Rails calculates the response codes for controller actions?

Given the following controller action:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update(user_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'show' }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

(I'm using the same view to show and edit the record)

With this positive test:

```
test "should update basic user information" do
  user = users(:jon)
  user.first_name="Jonas"
  put :update, :id => user.id, :merchant_user =>user.attributes
  assert_response :found
  user = Merchant::User.find(user.id)
  assert user.first_name == "Jonas", "Should update basic user information"
end
```

And a negative test is like this:

```
test "should not update user email for an existing email" do
  user = users(:jon)
  original_user_email = user.email
  existing_user_email = users(:doe)
  user.email=existing_user_email.email
  put :update, :id => user.id, :merchant_user =>user.attributes
  assert_response :success
  user = Merchant::User.find(user.id)
  assert user.email == original_user_email, "Should not update email for an exising one"
end
```

Updating the record successfully, causes a 302 response code, which I assume that rails defaults to 302 for the GET resource/:ID. A failure to update the record cause a 200 OK.

How are these response codes being calculated and how can I override them?

Thanks

Comment: There are diffrent codes returned for HTML and JSON requests. I think 200 OK is returned on saving error to ensure comatibility with browser behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See inline comments below

```
if @user.update(user_params)
  format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
  # 302, the save was successful but now redirecting to the show page for updated user
  # The redirection happens as a “302 Found” header unless otherwise specified.

  format.json { head :no_content }
  # 204, successful update, but don't send any data back via json

else
  format.html { render action: 'show' }
  # 200, standard HTTP success, note this is a browser call that renders 
  # the form again where you would show validation errors to the user

  format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  # 422, http 'Unprocessable Entity', validation errors exist, sends back the validation errors in json

end
```

if you look at `format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }` it uses the `status` option on `render` to be explicit about the HTTP status code
so you can do `render action: 'show', status: 422` or `render action: 'show', status: :unprocessable_entity` if you wanted to (you probably don't) - and render defaults to `200 Ok` (rails uses a symbol `:success` to alias `:ok` as well

see also:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Head.html

see [Getting access to :not_found, :internal_server_error etc. in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542339/getting-access-to-not-found-internal-server-error-etc-in-rails-3/5542703#5542703)
in your console `Rack::Utils::HTTP_STATUS_CODES` to view all status codes (the values are symbols in rails), i.e. `Unprocessable Entity` is `:unprocessable_entity`

Answer (score 1):

1. <del>I highly doubt your code is working as you use `update` instead of `update_attributes` in controller. `update` is a private method in ActiveRecord::Callback which is not for consuming publicly.</del> *Thanks for Michael's comment pointing out `update` is a replacement of `update_attributes` in Rails 4, though not mentioned in question.*
2. Testing response is unnecessary and it's even more unnecessary to break the conventional response code. Instead, check the effect taken on ActiveRecord, and the response body or path.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel, thanks for mentioning that. I did not know that yet, just checked and verified it's true.